# Passing parameters on redirect with last id saved in Yii

Tags: php, yii

is it possible to pass a parameter to the rediret function ?

I've tried

```
$this->redirect(array(Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer, 'id' => Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertId());
```

The id is the last saved id.

On getting lastinsertid, is there a better method, avoiding to query the DB.  Isnt a return value from the save command?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the [documents](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#redirect-detail):

```
public void redirect(mixed $url, boolean $terminate=true, integer $statusCode=302)
```

> **$url** :  the URL to be redirected to. If the parameter is an array, the first
>   element must be a route to a controller action and the rest are GET
>   parameters in name-value pairs.

So you could give a **string** like:

```
$this->redirect('http://www.google.com');
```

Or an **`array()`**:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller/action' , array('id' => $id , 'anotherParameter' => $id2)) );
```

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using `getLastInsertId()` as it might not always return what you previously have created. If you are using **Active Record** the ID property of the model will be populated after the save of this model.

So you can simly do:

```
$redirectId = $model->id;
```